# Angular 4 Cannot read property 'product_name' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I want to edit a product and show the details before update the product. I've developed a form and the related components and service however, I got an error message `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_name' of undefined` in my angular 4 app. I wrote the following in "update-product.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="productUpdateForm" (ngSubmit)="updateproduct()" class="form-signin" novalidate
        [class.was-validated]="productUpdateForm.invalid && (productUpdateForm.dirty || productUpdateForm.touched)">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading text-center">Update Product</h2>

   <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="dataInvalid">
      <p *ngFor="let error of formErrors">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="product_name" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="dataInvalid"
             placeholder="Enter Name" required [(ngModel)] = "data.product_name">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Name is required.
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="productUpdateForm.invalid" *ngIf="!formSubmitting">Update</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" [disabled]="formSubmitting" *ngIf="formSubmitting">Updating...</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And my update-product.component.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router, RouterModule, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaders }  from '@angular/common/http';
import { UpdateProductService } from './update-product.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-product',
  templateUrl: './update-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-product.component.scss']
})
export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit {

  productUpdateForm: FormGroup;
  dataInvalid = false;
  formErrors = [];
  formSubmitting = false;
  id:number;

  constructor(private UpdateProductService: UpdateProductService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder) { 
  this.createForm();
  }

    createForm(){
    this.productUpdateForm = this.fb.group({
      product_name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300)]]
    });
  }
   ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
    this.UpdateProductService.getProduct(this.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;
      } 
  }
}
```

Please note, the data are showing properly in the input box however, at console, I got the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `data` in your component.

```
    this.UpdateProductService.getProduct(this.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;  // there is no variable data in your component
      } 
  }
```

You need to declare it before using it.

```
export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit {

  data:any="";
```

Since you havent declared it and using `product_name` property of `data` in your html, it is throwing this error.

Comment: I have added data:any; as you said but, no luck. The error is still there.

Comment: add it like data:any="";

Comment: The above code (data:any="";) works, Please modify your answer so that I can mark this as Correct !

Answer (score 1):

You need to safety check the variable in the interpolation.

```
data?.product_name
```

in your example

```
      <input type="text" formControlName="product_name" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="dataInvalid"
             placeholder="Enter Name" required [(ngModel)] = "data?.product_name">
```

The above `ngModel`data is changed to `data?`. this will check for its existence.

Comment: Where I need to write it? means in which section/ which file?

Comment: in `.html` file, you need to change the nterpolations '{{}}

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara using safety check is the proper way of doing this in angular4

Comment: It would be great if you could modify your answer by giving an example. I'm unable to understand where I need to place the braces.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara i have updated with your example.

Comment: I did but it shows the error: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 20 in [data?.product_name=$event] in ng:///UpdateProductModule/UpdateProductComponent.html@11:47 ng:///UpdateProductModule/UpdateProductComponent.html@11:47
Empty expressions are not allowed ("lass="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="dataInvalid"
             placeholder="Enter Name" required [ERROR ->][(ngModel)] = "data?.product_name">
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Name is required.